# C# linq list find closest numbers

Tags: c#, list, linq, enumeration, closest

I have a list of numbers and I want to find closest four numbers to a search number.

For example if the search number is `400000` and the list is: `{150000, 250000, 400000, 550000, 850000, 300000, 200000)`, then the closest 4 numbers would be:

```
{300000, 400000, 250000, 550000}
```

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2) to order the list by the absolute value of the difference between each item and your search term, so that the first item in the ordered list is closest to your number, and the last item is furthest from the number. Then you can use the [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.7.2) extension method to take the number of items you need:

```
var list = new List<long> {150000, 250000, 400000, 550000, 850000, 300000, 200000};
var search = 400000;
var result = list.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x - search)).Take(4);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Output: `{400000, 300000, 250000, 550000}`

Comment: And, if you want _"The Price Is Right"_ rules (closest without going over), all you have to change is the lambda.

Comment: yes i tied but not giving me the right results. I passed the list {20000,30000,40000,60000,80000,90000}. Expecting result :{20000,30000,40000,60000} what I am getting is  {90000,80000,60000,40000}

Comment: @OwaisAhmed: Fiddle with the lambda expression to get it right.

Comment: my fault, invalid order. here tested solution (i'll edit this one) https://dotnetfiddle.net/Boolsn

Comment: @Flydog57 sorry what do you mean by that

Comment: It should be `OrderBy` if you want to get the closest values. `OrderByDescending` will put the items with the ***largest*** difference first.